# Check the date and time entered by user in UNIX

Tags: unix, shell, unix-timestamp

I have a Shell script which uses the date and time parameters entered by the user.
Date  as mm/dd/yyyy  and Time as HH:MM .
What would be the easiest means to check the user had entered the proper date [ like month should be less than 12.... for time MM should be less than 60...
Do we have any built in functions in UNIX for checking the timestamp?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this always bugs me: "Date as mm/dd/yyyy": that format is used only in North America. Consider using the ISO-8601 format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: LOL, let the bastards enter UNIX time, if they don't know it, they are not worthy users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the unix **date** tool to parse and verify it for you, and test the return code e.g.

A valid date, return code of 0:

```
joel@bohr:~$ date -d "12/12/2000 13:00"
Tue Dec 12 13:00:00 GMT 2000
joel@bohr:~$ echo $?
0
```

An invalid date, return code 1:

```
joel@bohr:~$ date -d "13/12/2000 13:00"
date: invalid date `13/12/2000 13:00'
joel@bohr:~$ echo $?
1
```

You can vary the input format accepted by **date** by  using the **+FORMAT** option ([man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date))

Putting it all together as a little script:

```
usrdate=$1
date -d "$usrdate"  > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Date $usrdate was valid"
else
        echo "Date $usrdate was invalid"
fi
```

Comment: try this : `date -d "1/12/2000 13:111111111100:00"`

Comment: Output is 'date: invalid date `1/12/2000 13:111111111100:00'', which is correct, no?

Comment: nil, this treated as a valid date string, and added exceeded minutes into hour, become something like `Wed Jan  7 17:44:00 SMT 939`

Comment: treated as valid, by whom? My version of date (8.5) flags it as invalid.

Comment: `date (coreutils) 5.2.1` treated as valid, don't be surprise, however, if `date (GNU coreutils) 5.97` it return as invalid date string

Comment: Some versions of `date` (e.g. GNU `date`) don't allow setting the input format (only the output format may be set). In fact, the man page you link to says as much.

Comment: Also, be aware that this method will allow a user to enter a date such as "last monday" which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` to check that the input conforms to the correct format:

```
if ! echo "$INPUT" | grep -q 'PATTERN'; then
   # handle input error
fi
```

where *PATTERN* is a regular expressino that matches all valid inputs and only valid inputs. I leave constructing that pattern to you ;-).

Answer (score 0):

(Late answer)

Something that you can use:

```
...
DATETIME=$1

#validate datetime..
tmp=`date -d "$DATETIME" 2>&1` ; #return is: "date: invalid date `something'"
if [ "${tmp:6:7}" == "invalid" ]; then
    echo "Invalid datetime: $DATETIME" ;
else
    ... valid datetime, do something with it ...
fi
```